# Sum returning NaN from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database, nan

I am trying to create a sum from a firebase value and a local value. But my sum keeps returning NaN. Can you see what im doing wrong? This is what I tried:

My local value sum which returns its total value good:

```
// here I  create the sum for the total amount
var total = 0;
function getData(){
    for (var i = 0; i < HoeveelheidArr.length; i++) { //my arrawy from user input which i extracted
       total += parseInt(HoeveelheidArr[i]);
    }
}
```

My other Functions which gets the DB value and creates the sum:

```
   //function update content from elemnt with value
    function gotData(data){
         var progressList = document.getElementById("progressList");
         var wemosRep = function(element, value){
         element.textContent = value;
    }

    //get value from db and auto pass update ony my page if change in value
    startWemosRep = firebase.database().ref('Reps/Value');
    startWemosRep.on('value', function(snapshot){
       wemosRep(progressList,snapshot.val());

       //my sum generating the error
       progressLeft =  (startWemosRep.val() - total); //this doesnt!

       console.log(progressLeft);
    });
```

For the DB variable startWemosRep, I also tried to leave out the ; .val(), parseInt(startWemosRep -total) and parseIn(startWemostRep) - total. None of which worked

All 3  return NaN what else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because at some point you are dealing with **badly formatted string** or **undefined** value.

I suspect that your **startWemosRep.val()** or **total** is undefined.

can you please check that?

to check it at runtime, you can use debugger inside chrome dev tools.

Comment: HI thank you for your resonse, Checked both, total is fine and showcases a number, SartWemosRep returns NaN when i parse it as Int. If I dont i just get a whole DB string like : wi {repo: di, path: Ot, queryParams_: mi, orderByCalled_: false}

Comment: you should definitely try to use chrome dev tools. you will be able to try out these conversions at real time that way and will figure out what the problem is 

Comment: If I use consolelog this.wemosRep I am getting undefined in the chome devtools. If I use without the im getting a whole formula  : ƒ (element, value){
        element.textContent = value;

    }

Comment: Upvoted, I have tried using that in the devtools. Didnt get any wiser from it..  The function is in order to fetch the value from the DB. I think im either 1, not storin the value right or 2, not parsing it right or 3, not summing it right.

Comment: Yeah, you are close to the answer 

Comment: I FIXED IT! ! I was using startWEmosGet as val to subtract from the total. Iw as supposed to use snapshot.val(). So simple damn. I can finally finishnthis.!

Comment: Shit I knew that syntax, it's snapshot.value().. anyways I'm glad you got that right 